# Fetching words from a string and change them to lower case, in Java.

Tags: java

Fetching words from a string. This is working fine.

```
String[] arrayOfWords = aNovelInAString.split("\\s+");
```

Need to capture all the words in lower case. Would have liked to have something like this

```
String[] arrayOfWords = aNovelInAString.split("\\s+").toLowerCase();
```

This of course *does not* work.

What is the best way to get to the same effect. I could iterate over the whole array and change words one by one. But I am querying to check if there is a better way of solving that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can obtain a lower case `String` from the original `String` before splitting it:

```
String[] arrayOfWords = aNovelInAString.toLowerCase().split("\\s+");
```

Comment: That worked :) And I guess it was just plain stupid of me not to think of this. Was too focussed on some other part of the code.